# Drawling normal distribution curve with mean and standard deviation in JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

I have an API when hit gives me a mean and a standard deviation. I want to generate a mean distribution curve based on the above two values. How can I do this using javascript(d3.js). I want a curve to be generated for different values of mean and sigma. I mean a good fitting curve should be generated irrespective of what mean and sigma I get from an API.

Comment: D3 doesn't do the fitting for you -- you would need to compute the data first. See e.g. http://racingtadpole.com/blog/curve-fitting-cdf-js-d3/

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

There are equations for calculating a normal distribution given a mean and standard deviation. The [wikipedia page for the normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) shows the density function, which is what you want.

So you'll want to generate this function based on the mean and variance (standard deviation squared) returned by the API, then generate points using this function and chart them using d3.js.